# Can the object you create with a constructor function ever itself be a function?

Tags: javascript

I hope this question makes sense. Can I ever do something like the following:

```
function constructor_function() {...code...};

var a = new constructor_function();

a();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a constructor returns an object, that will be the value of the `new ..` expression.  A function is an object, so you do what you want:

```
function ConstructorFunction() {
    return function () { alert("A function!"); };
}

var a = new ConstructorFunction();

a();
```

Comment: That just returns a function and doesn't do anything with the new state. There is no point in calling `new`. It's a needless inefficiency.

Comment: Hmm thanks! Do you know why the alert the following side triggers says "[object Object]" instead of "A String!"? code = function test() {return "A string!"}; var a = new test(); alert(a);

Comment: @zjmiller because you need to return an object with the `new` keyword. If you don't return an object then the return value is the object `this` which is created and used in the function `test`. To overwrite the default return value of `this` you need to return an object (A function is an object, a string is a string)

Answer (score 1):

```
function Wrapper(constr, func) {
    return function() {
        var f = func();
        constr.apply(f, arguments);
        return f;
    }
}

function ConstructorFunction() {
    return function() {
        console.log("A function");
    }
}

function Constructor() {
    this.foo = 42;
}

var MyFunction = Wrapper(Constructor, ConstructorFunction);
var o = MyFunction();
o(); // A function
console.log(o.foo); // 42
```

To both manipulate the `this` state as intended and have the object returned be a `function` is difficult to do without a lot of extra hoops to jump through.

This is about as easy I could make it. You have your standard Constructor function that manipulates `this` as an object. Then you have your ConstructorFunction which is the function you want the constructor to return. This must be a factor that returns a new function each time it's called.

You wrap the two together to get a function which returns an object which both has the returned function and the manipulation of state.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/A2Uhy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function from the constructor, but then it's not really a constructor. You can just use the function as a regular function, the `new` keyword is not needed:

```
function constructor_function() {
  return function() { alert(42); }
};

var a = constructor_function();

a();
```

As a function is an object, you can even add properties to it:

```
function constructor_function() {
  var t = function() { alert(42); }
  t.size = 1337;
  return t;
};

var a = constructor_function();

a();
alert(a.size);
```